# View having a onClickListener in swipable list view can't be swiped anymore, but only responds to onClick event

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event, swipe-gesture

I implemented a swipable listview following this url: https://jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview, only difference is that I only have MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and detect the movement in the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP based on the deltaX value. The custom view of the list item a layout like this wrapped in a Linearlayout:

TextView1 | TextView2 TextView3

before swiping, it looks like:

[image]

Initially TextView2 and 3 are hidden, When swiping this view, they will be displayed like:

[image]

I have onClickListener set for all 3 TextViews and it's found that with onClickListener set to TextView1, I can not swipe if starting from TextView1, and still able to swipe outside of TextView1 since TextView2 and 3 are initially hidden. It seems that TextView1 only responds to OnClickLisener.

I also tried to call these for TextView1:

```
setClickable(true);
setEnabled(true);
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

What have I missed? Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Editted:

I noticed that if I put my finger between the TextView1 and it's parent Linearlayout, then, the swiping will work. So it seems like the child view (TextView1) disabled its parent view (Linearlayout) onTouchListener due to the child view's onClickListener? How can I get the onTouchEvent when swiping start at the child view?

Answer (score 0):

I post the answer specific to my situation. Please check this url to get code of implementing swipable listview: https://jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview.

In my code, I attached the touch listener to the listview item's layout view (convertView):

```
convertView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDetector(viewHolder, position, data, mContext));
```

And I also attached the same touch listener to "TextView1" of the view holder for this convertView: (**This makes the swiping on "TextView1" work.**)

```
TextView1.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDetector(this, position, data, act));
```

Where

```
data - a java class holding the information for each list item;
position - a index of the list item
act / mContext - the activity instance
viewHolder - View holder class defined in the adapter
this - the Viewholder
```

Comment: Too bad, it turns out that swiping on TextView1 starts working, but onClick stops works.

Comment: got a workaround: in the ACTION_UP event when the deltaX is less than the threshold, I checked if the string id of the view is that of TextView1, if so, it's considered as a click on TextView1.